# Append to a pd.DataFrame, dynamically allocating any new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I'm wanting to aggregate some API responses into a DataFrame.

The request consistently returns a number of json key value pairs, lets say A,B,C. occasionally however it will return A,B,C,D.

I would like something comparible to SQL's OUTER JOIN, that will simply add the new row, whilst filling the corresponding previous columns as NULL or some other placeholder.

The pandas join options insist upon imposing a unique suffix for the side, I really don't want this.

Am I looking at this the wrong way?

If there is no easy solution, I could just select a subset of the consistently available columns but I really wanted to download the lot and do the processing as a separate stage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.concat` as it provides with all the functionality required for your problem. Let this toy problem illustrate the possible solution.

```py
# This generates random data with some key and value pair.
def gen_data(_size):
  import string
  keys = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
  return dict((k,[v]) for k,v in zip(np.random.choice(keys, _size),np.random.randint(1000, size=_size)))

counter = 0
df = pd.DataFrame()
while True:
  if counter > 5:
    break;

  # Recieve the data
  new_data = gen_data(5)

  # Converting this to dataframe obj
  new_data = pd.DataFrame(new_data) 

  # Appending this data to my stack
  df = pd.concat((df, new_data), axis=0, sort=True)

  counter += 1

df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(df.to_string())
```